How to update marker location on click?
I followed this example to create a simple map with a circle marker point on it: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-color.html
This is my current code:
import Feature from 'ol/Feature.js';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {Icon, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj.js';

const rome = new Feature({
  geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([12.5, 41.9])),
});

rome.setStyle(
  new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      color: '#BADA55',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
      src: 'data/dot.svg',
    }),
  }),
);

const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: [rome],
});

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
});

const tileLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [tileLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([2.896372, 44.6024]),
    zoom: 3,
  }),
});

And now I want to be able to click on the dot and change it's position to a new point given a new longitude and latitude.
I've looked in the docs for Point: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Point-Point.html
But they are really confusing, and I could not find the way to make the above point clickable and moved to a new location (in this case I just want to move it to a nearby location given a fixed longitude and latitude)
The docs are just really confusing

You need to listen for click events on the map and let OpenLayers find any features at that location.
map.on('singleclick', function (e) {
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
    if (f === rome) {
      f.getGeometry().setCoordinates(fromLonLat([28.9744, 41.0128]))
    }
  });
});

If the feature is Rome it will move to Istanbul.

Thank you! May you please help me understand how to search through these docs? Like how did you know that the event would be singleclick for example? I couldn't even find the list of events (But I was in the right direction as I was looking at the on method). Then, how did you know that forEachFeatureAtPixel exists and would do the job? The docs are very lacking and it feels like only someone who used that for a very long time would know what to look for

Also at first I thought about using the transform or translate methods of the Point object - will that be possible to do it with that?
